# What´s the random_state in DecisionTreeRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What's the difference between:
DecisionTreeRegressor(splitter='random') and DecisionTreeRegressor(splitter='best')

If both seem to throw random predictions, I don't get why do both implementations use the parameter random_state

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/vehicles_train.csv'
train = pd.read_csv(url)

train['vtype'] = train.vtype.map({'car':0, 'truck':1})
feature_cols = ['year', 'miles', 'doors', 'vtype']
X = train[feature_cols]
y = train.price

treereg = DecisionTreeRegressor(splitter='best')

for i in range(1, 10):
    treereg.fit(X, y)
    print treereg.predict([1994, 10000, 2, 1])
```

thanks!

Comment: [Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) for reference

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer this definitively, but this is what I suspect is happening:

Even for `splitter="best"`, the algorithm used inside the decision tree explores the features in a random order (as you can see [in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L380)). If `max_features` is not defined, it *should* explore all features and thus find the same best split regardless of the random state, as long as there is a **unique** best split.

My suspicion is that for the data you provided, at some point there are two possible splits that are equally good according to the specified criterion, and so the algorithm chooses the one it sees first.